# Save a file locally

Tags: asp.net

I want to save an XML file using XML serialization on the server and then restore the object value from the XML.

The problem is that the XML file keeps disappearing if I rebuild. How should I save a file and where to ensure it will remain there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review using [System.IO in ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/52/Basic-file-management-with-System.IO-in-ASP.NET) for a good starting point.

A safe store for your files is [APP_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337%28VS.80%29.aspx), as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that you're saving the file to your build directory, which is emptied and repopulated in the build process.  Have you looked into changing the location of the saved file?

Answer (score 0):

It is common to save XML files to the App_Data folder.

Comment: how do I save it to App_data? with path like ~/App_Data/myfile.xml?